# Como acceder a la información de un vídeo mientras es capturado en Android?

Tags: android, video, bufferedimage

Quiero cifrar un vídeo mientras esté es capturado por la cámara de un dispositivo Android, para ello voy a usar Media Códec y Media Muxer ya que Media Player no me permite trabajar con los bytes o buffer directamente, mi problema es que a Media Muxer le pasó por parámetro el fichero de salida lo que me impide cifrar la información antes, por lo tanto mi pregunta es si hay alguna forma de cifrar la información antes de que esta pase al archivo de salida, ya sea usando este método u otro.

```
`public class VideoEncoderCore {
private static final String TAG = "";
private static final boolean VERBOSE = false;

// TODO: these ought to be configurable as well
private static final String MIME_TYPE = "video/avc";    // H.264 Advanced Video Coding
private static final int FRAME_RATE = 30;               // 30fps
private static final int IFRAME_INTERVAL = 5;           // 5 seconds between I-frames

private Surface mInputSurface;
private MediaMuxer mMuxer;
private MediaCodec mEncoder;
private MediaCodec.BufferInfo mBufferInfo;
private int mTrackIndex;
private boolean mMuxerStarted;


/**
 * Configures encoder and muxer state, and prepares the input Surface.
 */
public VideoEncoderCore(int width, int height, int bitRate, File outputFile)
        throws IOException {
    mBufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();

    MediaFormat format = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(MIME_TYPE, width, height);

    // Set some properties.  Failing to specify some of these can cause the MediaCodec
    // configure() call to throw an unhelpful exception.
    format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT,
            MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatSurface);
    format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, bitRate);
    format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, FRAME_RATE);
    format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, IFRAME_INTERVAL);
    if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "format: " + format);

    // Create a MediaCodec encoder, and configure it with our format.  Get a Surface
    // we can use for input and wrap it with a class that handles the EGL work.
    mEncoder = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(MIME_TYPE);
    mEncoder.configure(format, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
    mInputSurface = mEncoder.createInputSurface();
    mEncoder.start();

    // Create a MediaMuxer.  We can't add the video track and start() the muxer here,
    // because our MediaFormat doesn't have the Magic Goodies.  These can only be
    // obtained from the encoder after it has started processing data.
    //
    // We're not actually interested in multiplexing audio.  We just want to convert
    // the raw H.264 elementary stream we get from MediaCodec into a .mp4 file.
    mMuxer = new MediaMuxer(outputFile.toString(),
            MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4);

    mTrackIndex = -1;
    mMuxerStarted = false;
}

/**
 * Returns the encoder's input surface.
 */
public Surface getInputSurface() {
    return mInputSurface;
}

/**
 * Releases encoder resources.
 */
public void release() {
    if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "releasing encoder objects");
    if (mEncoder != null) {
        mEncoder.stop();
        mEncoder.release();
        mEncoder = null;
    }
    if (mMuxer != null) {
        // TODO: stop() throws an exception if you haven't fed it any data.  Keep track
        //       of frames submitted, and don't call stop() if we haven't written anything.
        mMuxer.stop();
        mMuxer.release();
        mMuxer = null;
    }
}

/**
 * Extracts all pending data from the encoder and forwards it to the muxer.
 * <p>
 * If endOfStream is not set, this returns when there is no more data to drain.  If it
 * is set, we send EOS to the encoder, and then iterate until we see EOS on the output.
 * Calling this with endOfStream set should be done once, right before stopping the muxer.
 * <p>
 * We're just using the muxer to get a .mp4 file (instead of a raw H.264 stream).  We're
 * not recording audio.
 */
public void drainEncoder(boolean endOfStream) {
    final int TIMEOUT_USEC = 10000;
    if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "drainEncoder(" + endOfStream + ")");

    if (endOfStream) {
        if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "sending EOS to encoder");
        mEncoder.signalEndOfInputStream();
    }

    ByteBuffer[] encoderOutputBuffers = mEncoder.getOutputBuffers();
    while (true) {
        int encoderStatus = mEncoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(mBufferInfo, TIMEOUT_USEC);
        if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER) {
            // no output available yet
            if (!endOfStream) {
                break;      // out of while
            } else {
                if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "no output available, spinning to await EOS");
            }
        } else if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED) {
            // not expected for an encoder
            encoderOutputBuffers = mEncoder.getOutputBuffers();
        } else if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
            // should happen before receiving buffers, and should only happen once
            if (mMuxerStarted) {
                throw new RuntimeException("format changed twice");
            }
            MediaFormat newFormat = mEncoder.getOutputFormat();
            Log.d(TAG, "encoder output format changed: " + newFormat);

            // now that we have the Magic Goodies, start the muxer
            mTrackIndex = mMuxer.addTrack(newFormat);
            mMuxer.start();
            mMuxerStarted = true;
        } else if (encoderStatus < 0) {
            Log.w(TAG, "unexpected result from encoder.dequeueOutputBuffer: " +
                    encoderStatus);
            // let's ignore it
        } else {
            ByteBuffer encodedData = encoderOutputBuffers[encoderStatus];
            if (encodedData == null) {
                throw new RuntimeException("encoderOutputBuffer " + encoderStatus +
                        " was null");
            }

            if ((mBufferInfo.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG) != 0) {
                // The codec config data was pulled out and fed to the muxer when we got
                // the INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED status.  Ignore it.
                if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "ignoring BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG");
                mBufferInfo.size = 0;
            }

            if (mBufferInfo.size != 0) {
                if (!mMuxerStarted) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("muxer hasn't started");
                }

                // adjust the ByteBuffer values to match BufferInfo (not needed?)
                encodedData.position(mBufferInfo.offset);
                encodedData.limit(mBufferInfo.offset + mBufferInfo.size);

                mMuxer.writeSampleData(mTrackIndex, encodedData, mBufferInfo);
                if (VERBOSE) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "sent " + mBufferInfo.size + " bytes to muxer, ts=" +
                            mBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs);
                }
            }

            mEncoder.releaseOutputBuffer(encoderStatus, false);

            if ((mBufferInfo.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0) {
                if (!endOfStream) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "reached end of stream unexpectedly");
                } else {
                    if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "end of stream reached");
                }
                break;      // out of while
            }
        }
    }
}
}
`
```

El código anterior fue extraído del proyecto [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika) un vertedero de hacks de gráficos y medios de Android.

Comment: No entendi lo de cifrar , el formado video se lo guarda de acuerdo a como debe ser lo cual muxer lo hace si no no sera u video y no se podra ver.

Comment: Con cifrar me refiero a proteger dicha información con un algoritmo de encriptación o cifrado tal como el AES por ejemplo, por eso quiero acceder a los bytes del video cuando están en el buffer antes de que lleguen al fichero de salida, por lo tanto el vídeo solo se podrá reproducir por el usuario que posea la contraseña.

Comment: El muxer guarda el video como debe ser, como te dije lo que quieres hacer es aparte , obitenes el video e bytes y lo encryptas.

Comment: Ese es el problema, quiero encriptar el vídeo antes de que esté físicamente en el dispositivo, o sea, mientras aún está en memoria a medida que se va grabando, es eso posible?

Comment: Crea tu clase que guarde en formato video,  escribir todo lo saben busca como escribir bytes para tu video formato tu config.